# Partially Running Loops

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have to create a program that figures out the results of a game. In this game two boys Steve, and John, each take the same number of steps (S). However, each boy can only move forward or backward in increments. Steve can only move forward (A) amount of times, before he steps backward (B) amount of times, then goes back to A, then B, and so on until he reach S. The same for John, but instead of (A) for forward it is (C), and instead of (B) for back it is (D). The program prints "F" for each step forward and "B" for each step back.

An example of this game would be....
S: 12
A: 7
B:2
C:4
D:5

Steve: FFFFFFFBBFFF
John: FFFFBBBBBFFF

Each counter keeps going until S is reached. Both boys took 12 steps in total. Here is what i have so far....

```
    nforwardSteps = 0;
    nbackSteps = 0;
    nstepsTaken = nforwardSteps+nbackSteps;

    bstepsTaken = 0;
    bforwardSteps = 0;
    bbackSteps = 0;

    String dataIn;
    System.out.print("S: ");
    dataIn = input.readLine();
    S = Integer.parseInt(dataIn);

    System.out.print("A: ");
    dataIn = input.readLine();
    A = Integer.parseInt(dataIn);

    System.out.print("B: ");
    dataIn = input.readLine();
    B = Integer.parseInt(dataIn);

    System.out.print("C: ");
    dataIn = input.readLine();
    C = Integer.parseInt(dataIn);

    System.out.print("D: ");
    dataIn = input.readLine();
    D = Integer.parseInt(dataIn);



    while (bstepsTaken < S){
        while (bforwardSteps < C){
                System.out.print("For");
                bforwardSteps +=1;
        }
        bstepsTaken +=1;
        C +=C;
        while (bbackSteps < D){
                System.out.print("back");
                bbackSteps +=1;
        }
        bstepsTaken +=1;
        D +=D;
```

Everytime I run this, it only runs the loop once. How do I get my desired results?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, and we have no idea of the values you enter. Post a complete, minimal example, with hard-coded values instead of values entered by the user.

Comment: Note that you only print something inside the nested loops, and that you never reset bforwardSteps and bbackSteps, so these nested loops can only eecute once (unless of course you reset them in the part of the code that you havent posted).

Comment: @JBNizet [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) \[Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This king of issue is trivial to diagnose by executing the code step by step with your debugger, inspecting the values of the variables. Or at least by adding println statements to the code. You really need to learn doing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void showstep(Integer S, Integer A, Integer B, Integer C, Integer D){
        String Steve = "";
        for (int i = 0; i< S; i ++){
            if (i < A || i >= A + B){
                Steve += "F";
            }
            else{
                Steve += "B";
            }
        }
        String John = "";
        for (int i = 0; i< S; i ++){
            if (i < C || i >= D + C){
                John += "F";
            }
            else{
                John += "B";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Steve);
        System.out.println(John);
    }
```